# Having trouble with plugging in a function to a limit question

Tags: calculus, limits

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

find
$$\lim _{Δx\to 0}\frac{f\left(x+Δx\right)-f\left(x\right)}{Δx}$$

for the function
$$f(x)=3x-2$$

I tried plugging it in and got
$$\lim _{Δx\to 0}\frac{3\left(x+Δx\right)-2-\left(3x-2\right)}{Δx}$$

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to plug it in, I would assume that I need to cancel out the ΔX but am unsure of the steps that I need to take in order to do so.

Comment: Simplify the numerator.

Comment: That *is* the correct way.  Now just continue. $\lim _{Δx\to 0}\frac{3\left(x+Δx\right)-2-\left(3x-2\right)}{Δx}=\lim _{Δx\to 0}\frac{3x+3Δx-2-3x+2}{Δx}=\lim _{Δx\to 0}\frac{3Δx}{Δx}=\lim _{Δx\to 0}3=3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That substitution is correct, yes, since

$$\require{cancel}f(x+\Delta x) = 3(x+\Delta x) - 2$$

So now we just need to do some algebra to simplify:

\begin{align*}
&\lim _{Δx\to 0}\frac{3\left(x+Δx\right)-2-\left(3x-2\right)}{Δx}\\
&=\lim _{Δx\to 0}\frac{3x+3Δx-2-3x+2}{Δx} \tag{distribute}\\
&=\lim _{Δx\to 0}\frac{\cancel{3x}+3Δx\cancel{-2}\cancel{-3x}\cancel{+2}}{Δx} \tag{like terms cancel}\\
&=\lim _{Δx\to 0}\frac{3 \Delta x}{Δx} \tag{simplify the previous}\\
&=\lim _{Δx\to 0}\frac{3 \cancel{\Delta x}}{\cancel{Δx}} \tag{cancel common factor}\\
&=\lim _{Δx\to 0}3 \tag{simplify}\\
&=3 \tag{trivial limit}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Treat $\Delta x$ as a variable separate from $x$. I usually use $h$ instead so:
$$\frac{3(x+h)-2-3x+2}{h}=\frac{3h}{h}=3$$
Then clearly $$\lim_{h \to 0} 3 =3$$